# Convert HQL to SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to convert HQL to Spark.

I have the following query (Works in Hue with Hive editor):

```
select reflect('java.util.UUID', 'randomUUID') as id,
    tt.employee, 
    cast( from_unixtime(unix_timestamp (date_format(current_date(),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) as timestamp) as insert_date,
    collect_set(tt.employee_detail) as employee_details,
    collect_set( tt.emp_indication ) as employees_indications,
    named_struct ('employee_info', collect_set(tt.emp_info),
        'employee_mod_info', collect_set(tt.emp_mod_info),
        'employee_comments', collect_set(tt.emp_comment) )
        as emp_mod_details,
    from (
        select views_ctr.employee,
        if ( views_ctr.employee_details.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_details, null ) employee_detail,
        if ( views_ctr.employee_info.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_info, null ) emp_info,
        if ( views_ctr.employee_comments.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_comments, null ) emp_comment,
        if ( views_ctr.employee_mod_info.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_mod_info, null ) emp_mod_info,
        if ( views_ctr.emp_indications.so is not null, views_ctr.emp_indications, null ) employees_indication,
        from 
        ( select * from views_sta where emp_partition=0 and employee is not null ) views_ctr
        ) tt
        group by employee
        distribute by employee
```

First, What I'm trying is to write it in `spark.sql` as follow:

```
sparkSession.sql("select reflect('java.util.UUID', 'randomUUID') as id, tt.employee,    cast( from_unixtime(unix_timestamp (date_format(current_date(),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) as timestamp) as insert_date,    collect_set(tt.employee_detail) as employee_details,    collect_set( tt.emp_indication ) as employees_indications,  named_struct ('employee_info', collect_set(tt.emp_info),        'employee_mod_info', collect_set(tt.emp_mod_info),      'employee_comments', collect_set(tt.emp_comment) )      as emp_mod_details, from (      select views_ctr.employee,      if ( views_ctr.employee_details.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_details, null ) employee_detail,     if ( views_ctr.employee_info.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_info, null ) emp_info,      if ( views_ctr.employee_comments.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_comments, null ) emp_comment,       if ( views_ctr.employee_mod_info.so is not null, views_ctr.employee_mod_info, null ) emp_mod_info,      if ( views_ctr.emp_indications.so is not null, views_ctr.emp_indications, null ) employees_indication,      from        ( select * from views_sta where emp_partition=0 and employee is not null ) views_ctr        ) tt        group by employee       distribute by employee")
```

But I got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failute: Task not serializable:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper
>   -object not serializable (class : org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper, value:
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String$IntWrapper@30cfd641)

If I'm trying to run my query without `collect_set` function its work, It's can fail because struct column types in my table?

How can I write my HQL query in Spark / fix my exception?